# DataBinding of DataGridView and List<> with BindingSource

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, bindingsource

I'm trying to figure out how data binding with `BindingSource` is supposed to work 
I want a `DataGridView` to be populated with the content of a `List<>` upon update of the list.

I can see the `List` grow and verify it's being filled when I check the debugger. I thought the `BindingSource` would fire an event when the `List` is changed. But none of the available is fired. How do I become notified when the underlying list is changed?

I follow the instructions and have the following test code:

```
    Data d;
    BindingSource bs;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bs = new BindingSource();
        d = new Data();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bs.DataSourceChanged += new EventHandler(bs_DataSourceChanged);
        bs.ListChanged += new ListChangedEventHandler(bs_ListChanged);
        bs.DataMemberChanged += new EventHandler(bs_DataMemberChanged);
        bs.CurrentChanged += new EventHandler(bs_CurrentChanged);
        bs.CurrentItemChanged += new EventHandler(bs_CurrentItemChanged);

        bs.DataSource = d.list;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
    }
    // ... all the handling methods caught with a break point in VS.

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        d.addOneItem();
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`List<T>` doesn't support change events; `BindingList<T>` would be a good substitute to support this scenario, and it also supports item-level change events if your type `T` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

In 3.0 and above, there is also [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx), which acts similarly to `BindingList<T>`. It all comes down to interfaces such as `IBindingList`, `IBindingListView`, etc.

---

From comments; for a 2.0/3.0 example of adding a `Find` to `BindingList<T>`:

```
public class MyBindingList<T> : BindingList<T>
{
    public T Find(Predicate<T> predicate)
    {
        if (predicate == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("predicate");
        foreach (T item in this)
        {
            if (predicate(item)) return item;
        }
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

Note that in 3.5 (or in .NET 2.0/3.0 with LINQBridge and C# 3.0) you don't need this - any of the LINQ extension methods would do the same thing.

Comment: This works, thanks, however with BindingList I don't have a compare method, to which I could pass a predicate (which I found extremely useful). I was using that to prevent duplicates in the List... Will I get around looping through the list checking the existence by a object property?

Comment: You could use LINQ, which would work fine. Or subclass `BindingList<T>` and add some missing methods (very easy to do - let me know if you want to see how to do this with a predicate).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get notified when a property get's changed you'll need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

See [here](http://www.gavaghan.org/blog/2007/07/17/use-inotifypropertychanged-with-bindinglist/) for an example.

Comment: It wouldn't work with List<>, as Marc Gravell stated. So I'm following the approach with BindingList.