# Filtering binding source in C#

Tags: c#

My code is like this

```
BindingSource bs=new BindingSource();
List<Items> lstItems= ListItems();

bs.DataSource=lstItems;
```

I bind this bindingsouce to a gridview.

```
grd.DaataSource=bs;
```

Then I copy this original BindingSource to a separate BindngSource

```
BindingSource filterBs=new BindingSource();
```

Then I use a filter condition to Bindingsource

```
filterBs.Filter= "ItemCode='1' and cost>'200'";

grd.DataSource=null;
```

Re binding the datasouce of the grid to the filtered bindingsource.

```
grd.DataSource=filterBs;
```

But now also it shows all records in the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably run into other problems using a List with the BindingSource and trying to filter, so I would recommend this SO thread [DataBinding of DataGridView and List<> with BindingSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846464/databinding-of-datagridview-and-list-with-bindingsource).

Answer (score 2):

> Then I copy this original
>   BindingSource to a separate
>   BindngSource
>
> ```
> BindingSource filterBs=new BindingSource();
> ```

You're not copying it, you're creating a new BindingSource.

To copy it, you would instead do something like the following:

```
BindingSource filterBs = grd.DataSource;
```

Comment: Or simply --> BindingSoure filterBs = bs;    Right?

Comment: Even then, you're copying the reference to the old BindingSource, not creating a new one that looks like the old one.

Answer (score 2):

Binding Source depends on the underlying data source to provide filtering and sorting capability.  `List<>` does not support filtering, so therefore the your `BindingSource` does not support filtering.  You can confirm if this is your problem by looking at the `bs.SupportsFiltering` value in the debugger immediately after your `bs.DataSource=lstItems;` assignment.

[BindingSource.SupportsFiltering Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.supportsfiltering.aspx)

> If the list is not an IBindingListView, SupportsFiltering always returns false.

The only class I know of that implements `IBindingListView` is [`DataView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.DataView.aspx)