# Filter a BindingSource based on the rows of another DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, filter, bindingsource

I have two `DataGridViews` in Winforms. DataGrid1 is connected to a table that contains a list of jobs that need to be completed. Once someone completes a job, it's entered into a separate table as completed, which is connected to DataGrid2.

I need to filter the binding source for DataGrid1 so that when a job shows up as completed in DataGrid2 it's filtered out of DataGrid1. The current code I'm using only filters the binding source by the last entry in DataGrid2 and I need it to filter by all of the entries.

How do I filter the `BindingSourc`e for DataGrid1 based on all values of the a column of DataGrid2?

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGrid2.Rows)
{
    DataGrid1BindingSource.Filter = 
        string.Format("ColumnName <> '{0}'", row.Cells[1].Value);
}
```

Here is an example of all jobs in a data table, then the first grid which contains incomplete jobs and the second grid which contains completed jobs. The jobs which should be shown in Incomplete grid, are those jobs which are not in Completed jobs grid:

```
 __________        ____________        ___________
| All Jobs |      | Incomplete |      | Completed |  
|――――――――――|      |――――――――――――|      |―――――――――――|  
| JobTitle |      | JobTitle   |      | JobTitle  |  
|――――――――――|      |――――――――――――|      |―――――――――――|  
| Job 1    |      | Job 1      |      | Job 3     |  
| Job 2    |      | Job 2      |      | Job 4     |  
| Job 3    |      |            |      |           |
| Job 4    |      |            |      |           |
 ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾        ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾        ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
```

Comment: What technology? WinForms? WebForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: I'm using Winforms.

Comment: @ChrisSonger it's unclear what you are asking. Please reword the question and describe a little more about it, also show grid1 and grid2 example in initial state and say what would be the result of filter.

Comment: Since you are looping there, you override in every Loop-Step your last FilterCondition. As result, only the last row from grid 2 should apply to the filter

Comment: @RezaAghaei I've edited my question and included an image of how the DataGrids should work. I hope that helps clarify what I'm asking.

Comment: How can we detect a job is completed?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936323/filtering-binding-source-in-c-sharp) and make sure, your BindingSource supports filtering

Comment: @RezaAghaei both datasets are filled on Form Load and the filter is being applied on Form Shown. The user can then select a job that needs to be completed and complete it in a separate form. Once completed, all forms will close. So the filtering of data will only take place when the form is first opened.

Comment: @lokusking my BindingSource does support filtering and you're correct in that the looping is what's causing my filter to be overridden each time until it reaches the bottom of the list. I unfortunately cannot figure out how to make it look at the entire list all at once.

Comment: @ChrisSonger If you don't have a boolean field or something to detect which job is completed it's a bad design. You should have a single list of jobs. Then based on a boolean field you should show iincomplete jobs in grid1 and completed jobs in grid 2. Then the filter would be simply completed= true ad completed = false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before reading the answer, you should know if you don't have a `bool` field or something to detect which job is completed it's not a good design. You should have a single list of jobs. Then based on a `bool` field you should show incomplete jobs in first grid and completed jobs in second grid. Then the filter would be simply `Completed = true` and `Completed = false`.

Anyway, you can use `IN` in filter expression. It's enough to create a list of values which you want to use in filter, then create the filter this way:

```
var ids = this.dataGridView2.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                .Where(r => !r.IsNewRow)
                .Select(r => r.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
bs1.Filter = string.Format("Column1 NOT IN ({0})", string.Join(",", ids));
```

In the above example I supposed ids are `int` so for example `"Column1 NOT IN (1,2,3)"` will be the filter. For string ids, the filter would be `"Column1 NOT IN ('a','b','c')"`. So you can change the select statement like below:

```
.Select(r => string.Format("'{0}'",r.Cells[0].Value.ToString()));
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to compare the two tables against each other, so Grid1 has a list of jobs and Grid2 has a list of jobs completed, each having their own binding source. I'm trying to make it so that when a job is entered into the completed jobs Grid2 it gets filtered out of the jobs list in Grid1

Comment: Pay attention list of values is created from grid 2 and then the filter assigned to grid 1. This way those rows which are in grid 2, will not show in grid 1, only other rows will show in grid 1.

Comment: I now get Syntax error: Missing operand after 'JobTitle' operator. The title of the job has a space in it. I have used a design with a completed true/false field for other applications. The reason I'm not using it here is that the list of Jobs that need to be completed does not change. Once the row count of the list containing the jobs gets to zero the filter will be removed and the user will start over again with the full list.

Comment: I supposed the field type is `int`. For string type I posted an example.

Comment: Btw, You can accept an answer by click on check mark near the answer. Also when you accept an answer, it would be great if you also vote for the answer by click on up arrow near the post. It's not comppulsory at all, but it's common, reasonable and recommended. For more information about how does accepting answers work see this [post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow).

Answer (score 0):

This snippet is pretty ugly, but it should give you a hint of what to do:

```
var colname = YOURGRIDTOFILTER.Columns[INDEXOFCOLUMNTOFILTER].HeaderText;
            var filterString = colname+" <> ";
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGrid2.Rows)
            {
                filterString += "'" + row.Cells[1].Value + "' OR "+colname+" <> ";
            }
            filterString = filterString.Substring(0, filterString.LastIndexOf("OR"));
```