# DataSource doesn't show data when updated

Tags: c#, datagridview, datasource

I have a dataGridView, which should use a list as a dataSource. When running the application, it shows the grid fine with columns (auto-generated).
When a new Person-object is created and added to the list called Persons, it just add an empty row. When adding new persons after this, no changes is made.

The system is using a property in MainForm called Project, where it stores it's list used for the grid.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public static DataProject Project { get; set; }

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //show a dialog, creating the Project-object
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = Project.Persons;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
    }

    private void buttonAddPerson_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //show a dialog, creating a person and adding him to Project.Person (list).
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
        dataGridView1.Update();
    }
}
```

Here is the DataProject-object:

```
public class DataProject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Persons { get; set; }

    public DataProject()
    {
        Persons = new List<Person>();
    }
}
```

Comment: make DataProject : List<Person>

Comment: As DataProject also will contain other lists, this will be hard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataBinding of DataGridView and List<> with BindingSource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846464/databinding-of-datagridview-and-list-with-bindingsource)

Answer (score 1):

Create a global variable for BindingSource

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
```

and on button click just reset this bindingdource

```
bs.ResetBindings(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

dataGridView1.DataBind(); add this at the end. I had the same issue once, it worked for me!

```
public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //show a dialog, creating the Project-object
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = Project.Persons;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
        dataGridView1.DataBind();  
    }
```

Comment: It is actually ResetBindings() in the BindingSource, not the DataGridView.